# How to download a published github package on build action

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a github repository whose build action includes publishing docker image. This docker image needs a jar file from a different repository within the same organization.

I don't need to install this package, instead just download it as part of CI and bundle it as part of my docker image.

I have looked at https://github.com/actions/download-artifact but that does not seem to work for published packages.

Is there an action or some `curl` command that I can use to download the published package as part of CI ?

Comment: Where is it published to exactly?

Comment: Its published under github packages

Comment: Try this https://docs.github.com/en/rest/packages